# Convert Spark Java to Spark scala

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I am trying to convert my Java code to scala in Spark, but found it very complicated. Is it possible to convert the following Java code to scala? Thanks!

---

```
JavaPairRDD<String,Tuple2<String,String>> newDataPair = newRecords.mapToPair(new PairFunction<String, String, Tuple2<String, String>>() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Tuple2<String, Tuple2<String, String>> call(String t) throws Exception {
                MyPerson p = (new Gson()).fromJson(t, MyPerson.class);

                String nameAgeKey = p.getName() + "_" + p.getAge() ;

                Tuple2<String, String> value = new Tuple2<String, String>(p.getNationality(), t);
                Tuple2<String, Tuple2<String, String>> kvp =
                    new Tuple2<String, Tuple2<String, String>>(nameAgeKey.toLowerCase(), value);
                return kvp;
            }
        });
```

---

I tried the following, but I am sure I have missed many things. And actually it is not clear to me how to do the override function in scala ... Please suggest or share some examples. Thank you!

```
val newDataPair = newRecords.mapToPair(new PairFunction<String, String, Tuple2<String, String>>() {

        @Override
        public val call(String t) throws Exception {
            val p = (new Gson()).fromJson(t, MyPerson.class);
            val nameAgeKey = p.getName() + "_" + p.getAge() ;
            val value = new Tuple2<String, String>(p.getNationality(), t);
            val kvp =
                new Tuple2<String, Tuple2<String, String>>(nameAgeKey.toLowerCase(), value);
            return kvp;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried

Comment: This is what I tried:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Literal translations from Spark-Java to Spark-Scala typically don't work because Spark-Java introduces many artifacts to cope with the limited type system in Java. Examples in this case: `mapToPair` in Java is just `map` in Scala. `Tuple2` has a more terse syntax `(a,b)`

Applying that (and some more) to the snippet:

```
val newDataPair = newRecords.map{t =>                
    val p = (new Gson()).fromJson(t, classOf[MyPerson])
    val nameAgeKey = p.getName + "_" + p.getAge
    val value = (p.getNationality(), t)
    (nameAgeKey.toLowerCase(), value)
}
```

It could be made a bit more concise but I wanted to keep the same structure as the Java counterpart to facilitate the understanding of it.

Comment: I got " identifier expected but 'class'  found" at MyPerson.class on the line:  val p = (new Gson()).fromJson(t, MyPerson.class)   ... what am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: @Edamame oops - fixed - another java vs scala thing :-)   --- btw, I'm not familiar on how Guava's Gson would interop with Scala - might work as-is. Otherwise, you'll have to research further.